# how to create a javascript function with parameters in another javascript file to use within another javascript?

Tags: function, parameters, jqgrid, parameter-passing, javascript

hey, good day. im creating a program that would load a data from a server into a jqgrid. what im trying to do now is create a function from a separate javascript file and just use that function in my other javascript-jqgrid-load-data. here's my code in javascript:

```
    $("#tbl").jqGrid({
        url: '',                            
        datatype: 'local',      
        jsonReader : {              
            root: function(obj) {
            //some codes here

               return root;
            },          
            page: "page",                   
            total: "pageCount",     
            records: "rows",    
            repeatitems:false,  
            id: "0" 
        },

        serializeGridData: function(postData) {
            var jsonParams = {
                .
                .//some codes here
                .

                'sort_fields': postData.sidx
            };

            if (postData.sord == 'desc')
            {
            ..//some codes
            }           
            else
            {
            ...//some codes
            }

            jpar = jsonParams;
            return 'json=' + jsonParams;
        },

        loadError: function(xhr, msg, e) { 
            showMessage('msg error');
        },
        colNames:['ID',...'Type'],      
        colModel:[
        ...//col model
        ],

        rowNum:5,           
        .
        .
        .//some codes here
        loadonce:false,         
        caption: "Main Account Group"
    });
```

i want to separate the code:

```
         jsonReader : {             
            root: function(obj) {
            //some codes here

               return root;
            },  
            page: "page",                   
            total: "pageCount",     
            records: "rows",    
            repeatitems:false,  
            id: "0" 
         },
```

and this:

```
         serializeGridData: function(postData) {
            var jsonParams = {
                .
                .//some codes here
                .

                'sort_fields': postData.sidx
            };

            if (postData.sord == 'desc')
            {
            ..//some codes
            }           
            else
            {
            ...//some codes
            }

            jpar = jsonParams;
            return 'json=' + jsonParams;
        },
        loadError: function(xhr, msg, e) { 
            showMessage('msg error');
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374977/is-it-possible-to-include-an-event-in-a-javascript-function/5375479#5375479) your your next question so that it answer on both from your question. The main idea is that you can either use **global** functions or better redefine jqGrid defaults with respect of

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {/*your changes to the defaults*/});
```