# is it possible to include an event in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, events, function, jqgrid

i was just wondering if getting a jqgrid event from a  main javascript and separate it using another javascript in a form of function would work? what im trying to do is like this. i have a code :

```
     ...//some code here
     serializeGridData: function(postData) {
        var jsonParams = {
            'SessionID': $('#eSessionID3').val(),
            'dataType': 'data',
            'recordLimit': postData.rows,
            'recordOffset': postData.rows * (postData.page - 1),
            'rowDataAsObjects': false,
            'queryRowCount': true,
            'sort_fields': postData.sidx
        };

        if (postData.sord == 'desc')
        {
            ...//some code here
        }           
        else
        {
            ...//some code here
        }

        return 'json=' + jsonParams;
    },

    loadError: function(xhr, msg, e) { 
        showMessage('errmsg');
    },
            ...//some code here
```

i want to get this code and write this in another javascript file and make this as a function, so that my other file could use this one..is it possible?

i created something like this in my other javascrtip file where i planned to put all my functions. here's the code (functions.js):

```
function serialLoad(){
   serializeGridData: function(postData) {
      var jsonParams = {
         'SessionID': $('#eSessionID3').val(),
         'dataType': 'data',
         'recordLimit': postData.rows,
         'recordOffset': postData.rows * (postData.page - 1),
         'rowDataAsObjects': false,
         'queryRowCount': true,
         'sort_fields': postData.sidx
      };

      if (postData.sord == 'desc')
      {
          ...//some code here
      }           
      else
      {
          ...//some code here
      }
      return 'json=' + jsonParams;
   },

   loadError: function(xhr, msg, e) { 
       showMessage('errmsg');
   }
}
```

this isn't working and display a message syntax error. i don't know how to correct this. is there anyone who can help me.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the answer on your derect question. If you define in the *functions.js* file some global variable, for example, `myGlobal`:

```
myGlobal = {};
myGlobal = serializeGridData: function(postData) {
    // ... here is the implementation
};
```

you can use it in another JavaScript file which must be included after the *functions.js* file:

```
serializeGridData: myGlobal.serializeGridData
```

(just use such parameter in the jqGrid definition).

If you want to use the `serializeGridData` parameter  with the value in the most of your jqGrids you can overwrite the default value of `serializeGridData` in the *functions.js* file instead:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
    datatype: 'json',
    serializeGridData: function(postData) {
        // ... here is the implementation
    },
    loadError: function(xhr, msg, e) { 
        showMessage('errmsg');
    }
});
```

In the example I ovewride additionally default `datatype: 'xml'` jqGrid parameter to `datatype: 'json'`. It shows that in the way you can set default values of any jqGrid parameter.

What it seems to me you really need is to use [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) jqGrid parameter to rename some defaulf names of the standard jqGrid parameters. For example with

```
prmNames: {
    rows:"recordLimit",
    sort: "sort_fields",
    search:null,
    nd:null
}
```

you rename the standard `rows` parameter to `recordLimit`, the `sidx` to `sort_fields` and remove `_search` and `nd` parameters to be send.

Additionally you can use `postData` having some properties defined as the function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for details). For example:

```
postData: {
    SessionID: function() {
        return $('#eSessionID3').val();
    },
    rowDataAsObjects: false,
    queryRowCount: true,
    dataType: 'data',
    recordOffset: function() {
        var pd = jQuery("#list2")[0].p.postData;
        return pd.recordLimit * (pd.page - 1);
    },
    json: function() {
        var pd = jQuery("#list2")[0].p.postData;
        return {
           SessionID: $('#eSessionID3').val(),
           dataType: 'data',
           recordOffset: pd.recordLimit * (pd.page - 1),
           rowDataAsObjects: false,
           queryRowCount: true,
           sort_fields: pd.sort_fields
        };
    }
}
```

I used here both `json` parameter which you currently use and add parameters like `SessionID`, `queryRowCount` and so on directly in the list of parameters which will be send. Of course it is enough to send only one way (either `json` or the rest) to send the aditional information which you need.

Comment: wait...ok.. i think i should study your code... i believe this can help me... thank you for the help and your time... im new in jqgrid and json and i really appreciate your effort. i hope i can have a mind like yours Oleg...")

Comment: @jayAnn: You are welcome! If you will receive some additional question about the code later you can ask here your questions.

Comment: i've been reading your code many times and i still can't get it right...i see it so complicated. i dont know where to write the jQuery.extend({....}) (in main javascript or in the functions.js), and the postdata, idon't know where should i insert it and where should i write it.. thank you oleg:) and sorry if i can't hardly understand...

Comment: @jayAnn: You can do following: in the functions.js use `jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, ...)` to change any default parameters of jqGrid. In the way you can set `prmNames` or `serializeGridData` for example. Then in the main script you define jqGrid having no `serializeGridData` parameter, In the case as the default parameter will be used values from `jQuery.jgrid.defaults` which you changed in the functions.js.

Comment: @jayAnn: Helped this? Probably I just try to write an code example as an answer on your next question.

Comment: this help me, you help me... one more question. if i'm going to write another program that will using jqgrid, can this functions.js also be used? and also to my next, next jqgrid program?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing function declaration and object literal notation. This syntax: `property: value` is used when creating an object with object literal notation:

```
var obj = {
   prop: val,
   prop2: val
};
```

`serializeGridData` and `loadError` are properties of some object and you cannot define those by just putting them into a function.

One way would be to create two functions, one for `serializeGridData` and one for `loadError`, e.g.

```
function serialLoad(postData){
  var jsonParams = {
     //...
  };

  if (postData.sord == 'desc') {
      //... some code here
  }           
  else {
      //... some code here
  }
  return 'json=' + jsonParams;
}

function onError(xhr, msg, e) { 
   showMessage('errmsg');
}
```

Then you can assign them in your other file to the object:

```
// ... some code here
serializeGridData: serialLoad,
loadError: onError,
//... some code here
```

---

Another way is to pass the object in question to the function and assign the properties there:

```
function attachLoadHandler(obj) {
    obj.serializeGridData = function(postData) {
        //...
    };

    obj.loadError = function(xhr, msg, e) {
        //...
    };
}
```

Then you have to pass the object you created to that function:

```
attachLoadHandler(obj);
```

But I think the first approach is easier to understand.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but it didn't work...it didn't display my grid anymore on load..

Comment: there's no error on the console.... and yes, i never forgot to include my functions.js...

Comment: @jayAnn: I updated my answer, the declaration of the `onError` function was wrong.

Comment: you're first example shows an error  "missing ( before formal parameters
[Break on this error] function onError: function(xhr, msg, e) { \n"

Comment: @jayAnn: Yep, I already corrected it. Check my update and my comments.

Comment: there's an error message "invalid label
[Break on this error] obj.serializeGridData: function(postData) {\n"

Comment: @jayAnn: It seems it should be `obj.serializeGridData = function(postData)`... but it is correct in my code. Be sure you use the code I posted correctly.

Comment: yes, thank you... there's no error now but it still didn't show my grid on load...

Answer (score 0):

The second example is incorrect, as you are declaring a javascript object as the body of a function, what you *could* do is:

```
function serialLoad() {
    // Return an object with the required members
    return {
        serializeGridData: function(postData) { ... },
        loadError: function(xhr, msg, e) { ... }
    };
}
```

Comment: i don't know but i don't get my program right. the grid is gone onload..but thank you for the answer...

Comment: console shows an error message  "missing ( before formal parameters" in "function loadError: function(xhr, msg, e) { 
   showMessage('errmsg');
}
"

Comment: You need to post the above comment on @Felix's answer.

Comment: @jayAnn: Ah, that was a copy and paste mistake. Remove the second `function` keyword.

Comment: ahhh,,, i already correctly do it... and there's no error message now, but the grid doesn't show

Comment: @jayAnn, update your original answer with your code to initialise the jqGrid

Comment: and sorry for the wrong comment.. and thank you for your help ... :)

Comment: here is my grid declaration....<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/css/ui.jqgrid.custom.css" />  
  <script type="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="javascript" src="js/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="javascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"</script>  <script type="javascript" src="js/grid.base.js"</script>
  <script type="javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"</script><script type="javascript" src="function.js"></script>